# jQuery.width() and height() returns different value on IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am showing a nvd3 chart on bootstrap modal. I specified width and height of modal-body with css:

```
#trendModal .modal-dialog {
    width: 800px;
}

#trendModal .modal-body {
    height: 400px;
}

<div class="modal fade" id="trendModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="trendModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="trendModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="trend-container">
                <svg></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I try to get width and height of modal, I get different answer on IE and Chrome:

```
width = $("#trendModal .modal-dialog").width(), //IE: 800, Chrome:780
height = $("#trendModal .modal-body").height(), //IE: 400, Chrome:360
```

It looks like Chrome deduct some padding/margin automatically while IE doesn't.
Does anyone know how this comes? If I want to unify behavior, what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: you may want to try playing with the `box-sizing` property, it might make it work better.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var width = $("#trendModal .modal-dialog").outerWidth()
    height = $("#trendModal .modal-body").outerHeight();
```

These give you the total height and width of the element including any margin and padding they might contain.

Answer (score 0):

There can be an issue in Chrome where the height/width is calculated with the document ready trigger, which won't take into account how the content could alter the width/height. Have you tried $(document).load(...)?

Comment: I call $.width and height in an event handler, where I call nvd3 and going to show the modal dialog. I am pretty sure that whole page has been loaded when modal shows up.